# Can you use one method to add items to 3 different implementations of a Priority Queue?

Tags: java, generics

I am doing an assignment for University which involves custom implementations of a Priority Queue. Each item in the queue will be a `Node<E>` storing the element and its priority (E, p). The overall field is meant to be of type `ArrayList<Node<?>>` and the 3 Implementations will be an -

- unsorted queue with items being added on the end, and removed by the highest priority which has been on the queue for longest - type `ArrayList<Node<String>>`
- sorted queue with items being removed from the front of the queue and added before the first item of the next lowest priority - so something of priority 2 will be added between the items of priority 1 and 3. -  type `ArrayList<Node<String>>`
- A sorted queue of Queues where each Node element is an array list of items with the same priority  -  type `ArrayList<Node<ArrayList<String>>>`

Each with their own enqueue, dequeue etc methods.

I was wondering if I could define a single method which will work with all three implementations of the Priority Queue as they correspond to the same field in the Application, and the respective enqueue methods of the queue types being called depending on the definition of the field.

Comment: Yes, it's called a Strategy pattern.  In Java you create an interface or abstract class and you give it three different sub-class implementations.  This can be useful for testing as you only need to write one set of tests which you can apply to all of them by using different implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Define an *interface* for the methods of a priorityQueue and than make three implementations of the interface.

```
interface PrioQueue{
  void enqueue(Node node);
  Node dequeue();
}

class PrioQueueVersion1 implements PrioQueue{
   ....
}

class PrioQueueVersion2 implements PrioQueue{
   ....
}

class PrioQueueVersion3 implements PrioQueue{
   ....
}
```

Comment: Done that already. But I need to make an application which I can use to choose the implementation I wish to use, using methods within this application class I then need to populate the queue either manually or from a file, now it would be much simpler if I could make a method which will implicitly do all three depending on the definition of the field which depends on the implementation method it was defined in.

Comment: @wsmccusker I am not understanding what you are having trouble with, if you have three different implementations of the interface polymorphism will ensure that the `enqueue` method for a specific type is called within your method.

Comment: Well I was slightly confused as well, which was the reason for me asking the question in the first place. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Extending upon MrSmith's answer, if you already have three separate implementations of your interface you can just use the polymorphism via interfaces to get the functionality you require. I have posted a small example below:

```
public interface PrioQ
{
    public void enqueue(Node n);
}

public class A implements PrioQ
{
    public void enqueue(Node n)
    {
      System.out.println("Enqueue from A");
    }
}

public class B implements PrioQ
{
    public void enqueue(Node n)
    {
      System.out.println("Enqueue from B");
    }
}

public class C implements PrioQ
{
    public void enqueue(Node n)
    {
      System.out.println("Enqueue from C");
    }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      List<PrioQ> queues = new ArrayList<>();
      queues.add(new A());
      queues.add(new B());
      queues.add(new C());


      for(PrioQ q : queues){
          q.enqueue(new Node());
      }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enqueue from A 
Enqueue from B
Enqueue from C
```

This is a small example, and probably not how you would use it in your application, but hopefully it will help reinforce my point about polymorphism.